# Sending geographic data from Postman?

Tags: postgis, java, well-known-text, hibernate-spatial

I am trying to create a GIS app using Java, Spring and Hibernate.

I send a JSON from Postman like this:

```
{
    "pointName":"any location",
    "geom":"POINT(-71.060316 48.432044), 3857"
}
```

The JSON is received by the Controller Class and sent to a Converter Class where the information that arrives as String is converted to geometry with the following method:

```
public static Geometry wktToGeometry(String wellKnownText) 
              throws ParseException {

                return new WKTReader().read(wellKnownText);
            }
```

But once the information is processed by this method, 3857 dissapears and I have the following error when I try to save in the DB:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (3857)
```

This is because the reference system has been removed in the wktToGeometry method, and it is interpretated as reference system 0.

How should I format the JSON?

Comment: What is the set SRID for your postgres database?

Comment: The SRID is 3857

Comment: Your coordinate looks to be in a geographic CS, not Web Mercator (unless you're mapping [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island)), and WKT doesn't actually include the SRID at the end (that's EWKT), so you've got multiple issues.

Comment: Which wkt reader are you using? How do you write to the database?

Comment: I am using " com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.WKTReader()" I write to the DB with save method of Spring´s crud repository

Answer (score 1):

At the end I have sorted it out. In the converter class, where the info from the json is setted to the objet, I have done like this:

```
public static GeometryEntity convertToGeometryEntity(NonGeometryEntity nonGeometry) throws ParseException {

    GeometryEntity geometryEntity = new GeometryEntity();

        if(nonGeometry.getUserId() != null) {
        geometryEntity.setUserId(Long.parseLong(nonGeometry.getUserId()));
        }

        geometryEntity.setPointName(nonGeometry.getPointName());
        geometryEntity.setGeom(wktToGeometry(nonGeometry.getGeom()));

        geometryEntity.getGeom().setSRID(3857);

        return geometryEntity;

    }
```

I have setted the SRID property straight away on the converter, and the info is saved ok in the db:

```
2019-05-19 20:34:57.553 DEBUG 6908 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into geometries (geom, point_name, user_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```